# <script> tag not been processed in textarea

Tags: php, mysql, apache, textarea

To demonstrate XSS attack, I am building a web app which does the following:

1. Works like a forum
2. Takes posts from users via a HTML textarea and store these messages in the mysql db
3. Displays all posts from the users on a thread. The objective is to show an XSS attack such as `alert("attack");` due to insufficient filtering of the input.

I am using a MySql db with Apache and PHP.

On entering the following input into the textarea:

```
<script>alert("attack");</script>
```

The data is just not being added to the DB and the $_POST method in the page which stores the posts into the database is returning an empty string. However, all other cases are working. I have so far not used any special functions used for input filtering in PHP, as this is an app to demonstrate XSS.

However, on manually adding the above script into the DB, the expected alert box pops up.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: What does the php that processes the input look like or do you use a framework?

Comment: One code snippet worth billion words. Instead of writing "$_POST method returns empty string" which makes no sense, you'd better post **a code** you're running in your tests.

Comment: Reposting the code I had added in the comment below. The code in the post message page is:'<h3>Enter your message here:</h3> <form action="addmessage.php" method="post"> <textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="50" wrap="soft"> </textarea> <p> <input type='Submit'> </p>' The code in the addmessage.php page is: 'echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you escape the input data with mysql_real_escape_string or similar? If you don't your quotes will probably mess with the generated SQL query.

Comment: No, so far, I haven't added the insert query into the PHP page. I was trying to echo the message from the POST object received on clicking the submit post button. However, anything other than within '<script>' tag is echoed fine.

Comment: @Rishabh: Perhaps try outputting with `htmlspecialchars()`? It may be output but just not triggering (for whatever reason).

Comment: Just for reference, the code in the post message page is:'<h3>Enter your message here:</h3>
<form action="addmessage.php" method="post">
 <textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="50" wrap="soft">
 </textarea>
 <p>
 <input type='Submit'>
 </p>' The code in the addmessage.php page is: 'echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);'

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks. The addition of htmlspecialchars() has solved the problem now! Cheers.

Comment: @Rishabh if that solves it, your issue was probably something else altogether. It would still be a good idea to show your code I think

Comment: Yes, so the addition of the htmlspecialchars is causing the <script> tags to be displayed too. I have added htmlspecialchars to the above code now.